# Error while parsing Json format data in c#

Tags: c#, json

I'm working on .net core api and angular 7. I'm calling my api from angular project and passing json formatted data as an input in api. I want to parse that json formatted data and get each values from that data and pass it into procedure.
I'm getting below error while parsing the data:

> The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string)' has some invalid arguments

Here is my json formatted data:

```
{
    "bu":2,
    "level":60,
    "location":124160,
    "month":"FEB",
    "year":2018,
    "PROCNAME":"proc_plan_wise_adhoc_rpt_n#200",
    "CLIENTID":"CIPQ",
    "REPCODE":"A0200"
}
```

I want to get values of bu, level, location etc... into variables and pass it into procedure, how to get those values?

here is my api code:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("bindgenericreports")]
public IActionResult BindGenericReports([FromBody]dynamic data)
{
    try
    {
        rs = new ResponseModel();
        ReportDL objReportDL = new ReportDL(_configuration);
        var details = JObject.Parse(data); //i'm getting error in this line

        string bu = details["bu"].ToString();

        //rs = objReportDL.BindGenericReports(data);
        return Ok(rs);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
        rs = null;
    }
}
```

what can be the issue? please help.

**Update**

[image: postman]

[image: .net core]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193062/discussion-on-question-by-shreyas-pednekar-error-while-parsing-json-format-data).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is already provided in the error message.

> The best overloaded method match for
>   'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(string)' has some invalid
>   arguments

You are trying to parse a dynamic that apparently is not a string.
Try converting the dynamic to a string value.
If it is a string value you will be able to parse it.

```
var details = JObject.Parse(data.ToString());
```

**Update from OP**

The Json you are sending with Postman is not correct.
Try parsing the json with [JsonLint](https://jsonlint.com/) for creating valid Json

Comment: Yeah I guess there is an issue with json data

Comment: Yes there's an issue with json data